# How to avoid offset when getting position coordinates(top,left) of sibling inner div

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I have a structure like this:

```
<body>
     <div class="a">
        <div class="b">
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="c">
     </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.a { position:absolute; }
.b { position:absolute; }
.c { position:absolute; }
```

- Result:
  [image]
  Here block is outside "a". Coordinates: top: 100px; left: 100px
- Expected:

[image]

```
<body>
 <div class="a">
    <div class="b">
      <div class="c"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

coordinates: top: 100px; left: 100px (the same), but "c" is inside "b".

As a result, using same coordinates, we get offset in first case. How can i avoid it? Thanks!

Comment: element.getBoundingClientRect() solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Made **two snippets**;

1) **Hard fix** with your current structure: (Use **position:relative** on parent container and **position:relative** on children)

```css
.wrapper{
  width:100px;
  position:relative;
}

.a{
  width:100px;
  height:80px;
  border:1px solid black;
  position:relative;
}

.b{
  width:60px;
  height:40px;
  border:1px solid black;
  position:absolute;
  margin: auto;
  z-index:1000;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.c{
  width:60px;
  height:40px;
  border:1px solid black;
  top:75%;
  left:80%;
  z-index:1000;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="b">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

2) Suggestion, **cleaner fix**:

```css
.a{
  width:120px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  position:relative;
}

.b{
  position:absolute;
  width:80px;
  height:60px;
  border:1px solid black;
  top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
}

.b-wrapper{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.c{
  position:absolute;
  width:80px;
  height:60px;
  border:1px solid black;
  top:100%;
  left:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="b-wrapper">
      <div class="c"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, i'll try to make it clear. Inside "a", "b" has own field with it coordinates. 
Meanwhile, inside  "body" "c" , using the same coordinates have the different position on canvas. 
So the question is how to tell "c" that he is not in "body" but in "a", but in fact, "c" are still  in "body"

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't understand your question well. Bet here is the snippet i made, 
exactly how you picture it.

```css
.container{
  max-width: 200px;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-flex;
}

.a{
  position:relative;
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  border: 2px solid #222;
}

.b{
  position:absolute;
  border: 2px solid #f69;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  left:50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.c{
  position:absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid brown;
  bottom: -30px;
  right: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

     <div class="a"> a
        <div class="b">
        b
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="c">c
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried use class 'b' instead of 'c'?

```
<body>
 <div class="a">
    <div class="b">
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="b">
 </div>
```

Comment: I can't change those classes. That the problem